# Is my webgl FBO color attachment being cleared?

Tags: webgl, regl

I'm trying to render something to texture using a library called `regl`. I manage to render an effect using two render targets and i see the result in one.

Capturing the frame after i've done rendering to the target looks like this, and it represents a screen blit (full screen quad with this texture). This is how i would like this to work.

[image]

Once i pass this to some other regl commands, in some future frame, this texture attachment seems to get nuked. This is the same object that i'm trying to render with the same resource, but the data is gone. I have tried detaching the texture from the FBO, but it doesn't seem to be helping. What can i be looking for that would make this texture behave like this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being a problem with Regl and WebViz. I was calling `React.useState` to set the whatever resource that regl uses for the texture. For some reason, this seems like it was invoked, which "resets" the texture to an empty 1x1.